# Text Values are differing

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code written to create a table copying information from various spreadsheets which use a common template. I'm facing a weird issue where `Range().Value` is returning the correct value, but the `Worksheets.Range.Value` is returning something completely way off!

[image: code & watch window]

I don't know where this value is coming from. In fact this value does not exist in the entire workbook either. I'm clueless. If someone can please throw some light!

I tried to run the code line by line, but there are two different values appearing on the watch for the same exact line of code.

Comment: It's the other way round. Worksheets.Range.Value is the correct value, and Range.Value is not. You have selected the subexpression `Range(...).Value` in the IDE, thus forcing it to evaluate it as a standalone expression. So it did, throwing away the preceding `Worksheets(i).` that qualifies the range, turning it into `ActiveSheet.Range(...).Value`.